# How to blur a portion of a view in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, viewmodifier

I'd like to blur a portion of a camera view in SwiftUI. Like a blurred frame.

My idea was to create a modifier for the camera view like the one in the code below.
However when I apply the modifier the blurred content `content.blur(radius: 7)` is being **clipped** too!

Can you please help me understand why this is not working?

```
struct MaskedCameraBlur: ViewModifier {
    // This is just the store in which the cropArea is saved
    @EnvironmentObject var dataStore : MyDataStore

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
         ​​ZStack {
            ​​content.blur(radius: 7) // this should not be clipped 
            ​​content.clipShape(Rectangle().path(in: dataStore.cropArea))
         ​​}
    }
}
extension View {
  func maskedCameraBlur() -> some View {
    self.modifier(MaskedCameraBlur())
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**

I want to add that I was able to solve my problem by using a `UIVisualEffectView`. [See the solution in my github](https://github.com/giomurru/blurred-edges-view/blob/master/BlurredEdgesView/MaskedCameraBlur.swift)

However I still would like to achieve the same goal using only pure SwiftUI and I'd really appreciate if you can point me in the right direction. Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/67381895/12299030?

Comment: @Asperi no, it does not.